# PHP access global variable in function inside other function

Tags: php, global-variables

I have file **a.php** that looks like

```
function func_1() {
  inlude_once(b.php);
  $somevar = 'def';
  func_2($somevar);
}
```

and **b.php** that looks like

```
$some_global_var = 'abc';

function func_2($var) {
  global $some_global_var;
  echo $some_global_var.$var;
}
```

And for some reason I get only ***def*** as a result, why func_2 don't see $some_global_var ?

Comment: Try passing as a parameter

Comment: it works fine, but what if I want to use is as global variable?

Comment: Some hostings have implicitely set register_globals directive to off. Check your php.ini.  Generally, global variables are not considered as a good practice. Can you avoid them?

Comment: Your code is pretty inter-winded which makes it hard to track scope and execution order. `$some_global_var = 'abc';` might but must not set a global variable (in your case it is a local variable), also include_once will make the assignment to only run once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you forgot the scope of `func_1`. So when you include your define this is how your code appears to PHP

```
function func_1() {
   $some_global_var = 'abc'; // <- this is inside the scope of the parent function!

    function func_2($var) {
      global $some_global_var;
      echo $some_global_var.$var;
    }
  $somevar = 'def';
  func_2($somevar);
}
```

You're doing it *inside* `func_1`. So the variable was never really available in the global scope. If you defined `$some_global_var = 'abc';` outside, then it's in the global scope.

What you should do is inject this as an argument instead. Globals are a bad practice

```
function func_1() {
   $some_global_var = 'abc'; 

    function func_2($var, $var2) {
      echo $var2 . $var;
    }
  $somevar = 'def';
  func_2($somevar, $some_global_var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `global` in front of it.

per the PHP docs

> Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

you may have an issue with an include file getting in the way

Comment: Where should I put global?

Comment: Incorrect. Even if you `global` the variable in the include it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I mocked this just to double check. PHP throws out `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in` if I global the variable in the include